# Radon-Nikodym derivative in a compact Hausdorff space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space where $X$ have infinitely many points and the topology is non-discrete, $m$ be a regular probability measure defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$, and $g$ an homeomorphism of $X$. Suppose that the image measure $g_{\ast}m$ (defined by $g_{\ast}m(O) = m\big[g^{-1}(O)\big]$ for each Borel subset $O$) is equivalent to $m$. Then, for each $F\in C(X)$, I will have:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\hspace{0.6cm} \int_X F(x)\frac{d\,g_{\ast}m}{d\,m}(x)\,dm(x) = \int_X F(x)\,d(g_{\ast}m)(x)\\
& = \int_X F(x)\, dm(g^{-1}(x)) = \int_X F\circ g(x)\,dm(x)
\end{aligned}
$$

Define $\phi_m$ to be the positive linear functional defined by $m$ (and defined on $C(X)$) and $\phi_{g_{\ast}m}$ similarly, $I = \{F\in C(X): \phi_m(\vert\,f\,\vert)=0\}$ and $I_g = \{F\in C(X): \phi_{g_{\ast}m}(\vert\,f\,\vert) = 0\}$. Then the image of the following mapping:

$$
M: I_g\rightarrow I,\hspace{0.3cm} F(x) \mapsto F(x)\frac{d\,g_{\ast}m}{d\,m}(x)
$$
is equal to the image of the action (restrcited on $I_g$) defined by $g\bullet F(x) = F\circ g(x)$. Obviously both mappings are invertible and the action is a isometric isomorphism between $I_g$ and $I$. My questions are:

1. Since the action $F\mapsto g\bullet F$ is multiplicative, $M$ will never coincide with the action unless $g$ is the identity. In this case what can we tell about the local range of $(d\,g_{\ast}m/d\,m)$?
2. Is it true that, when $X$ has non-empty homeomorphism group, for each regular probability measure $m$, there exists a non-identity element $g\in\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ (the homeomorphism group of $X$) such that $m$ is equivalent to $g_{\ast}m$?
3. Given a non-trivial countable subgroup $G\subseteq\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$, will there exist a regular non-atomic probability measure $m$ such that $g_{\ast}m\sim m$ for each $g\in G$?

**Update**: Let $m$ be a probability regular non-atomic measure and assume $g\in\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ satisfies $m\sim gm$. According to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417723), we can find a compact set $C_{\epsilon}$ such that both $m(C_{\epsilon})$ and $gm(C_{\epsilon})$ are less than $\epsilon$. I tried to use this and the **Urysohn's Lemma** to decide the local behavior of the derivative but failed. Any hints will be appreciated.

**Update2**: From the **Corollary 6.2.2** in **Measures on topological space** written by *V.I.Bogachev* ([link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/bf02432851)), for a fixed $g\in\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$, one can find a Radon probability measure $m$ (and hence regular when $X$ is compact) such that $g_{\ast}m = m$. In such case, compared to my original question, I suppose it would not be too greedy to ask, given $m$ a probability measure, is it possible to find a subgroup $G\subseteq\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ such that $g_{\ast}m\sim m$ for each $g\in G$.

Comment: Your compact Hausdorff space can have no homeomorphisms at all (there are many such spaces among continua), in which case your question 2 has a negative answer. So you should restrict the class of considered compact Hausdorff spaces to obtain something interesting.

Comment: Concerning your question 3, then for any compact subgroup $G$ of the homeomorphism group of $X$ there exists the unique Haar measure on $G$ and its image under the action should be a probability measure on $X$, which is unvariant with respect to the action. If $G$ is non-compact, for example, if $G$ is the whole homeomorphism group of the (say) Cantor set, then the action has no invariant measure even in your weak sense.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. About your first comment, could you specify the condition for $\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ to be non-trivial? I should have mentioned the space have infinitely many points, the topology is non-discrete and so on, but I suppose you mean other conditions.

Comment: About your second comment, I decided to only consider the case where $G$ is countable, so that it would be hard for $G$ to be compact, and hard for an infinite space $X$ to have $\operatorname{Homeo}(X)$ countable.

Comment: Manifolds modeled on various model spaces (like $\mathbb R^n$ or Hilbert cube) usually are topologically homogeneous, which means that for any points $x,y$ there exists a homeomorphism $h$ such that $h(x)=y$.

Comment: I posted an attempt to the third answer but then was blocked by a few more questions. Please feel free to add extra conditions that you believe is necessary for answering any of the questions above. For instance, should there exist a necessary condition for the space $X$ to have a non-trivial homeomorphism group, please feel free to add it to your post, and it would be also great to see an answer when $X$ is a general topologically-homogeneous space.

Comment: Concering your third question: I think the property you are looking for is called "(left/right) amenable" (as in amenable groups). Although I am not so sure that what you get as an invariant measure must be non-atomic. Examples of groups that is not amenable are free groups.

Comment: @JulianHölz If by "left-amenable", you mean $\mu(gA) = \mu(A)$ for all $g\in G$, I suppose it would be easier to start from searching for a $\mu$ such that "$\mu(g\cdot)\sim\mu(\cdot)$ for all $g\in G$. If I let $\delta_x$ be the Dirac measure defined on $x\in X$, then $g\delta_x = \delta_{gx}$. Since $G$ is assumed to be countable, the sum of $\delta_{gx}$ (after multiplying coefficients to make the infinite sum equal to $1$ will be a regular but very atomic probability measure. Since this example exists even when $X$ is just locally compact, I prefer to search for a non-atomic one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer for 2 is **no**. I will state some counter-examples below, after some partial results.

### A Necessary condition involving the support

From now on, all measures are Borel probability measures. For every measure $\mu$, define its support
$$\mathrm{Supp}(\mu) := \overline{\{ x : \forall V \text{ open with } x \in V, \mu(V)>0 \}} .$$

We have $\mathrm{Supp}(g_*\mu) = g(\mathrm{Supp}(\mu))$.
Indeed, let $x$ be in $\mathrm{Supp}(g_*\mu)$, then for every $V \ni x$ open, $0<g_*\mu(V) = \mu(g^{-1}(V))$. From there we can see that $g^{-1}(x) \in \mathrm{Supp}(\mu)$.

An immediate consequence of the definition is that two equivalent measures have the same support. This gives us the following Lemma:

**Lemma:** *For every homeomorphism $g$, if $\mu$ and $g_*\mu$ are equivalent, then $g(\mathrm{Supp}(\mu)) = \mathrm{Supp}(\mu)$.*

### Partial answer for measures supported on a strict subspace

**Proposition 1 (positive answer to 2.):** *If for every open set $V \notin \{\emptyset, X\}$, there is a homeomorphism $g$ of $X$ such that $g(V) = V$ and $g|_V \neq id$, then for every $\mu$ with $ \mathrm{Supp}(\mu) \neq X$ we have a non-identity $g$ such that $\mu$ and $g_*\mu$ are equivalent.*

Indeed, fix $V = X \setminus \mathrm{Supp}(\mu)$, and take $g$ given by the assumption. The assumption of Proposition 1 is true on many obvious examples.
Note the condition that $\mathrm{Supp}(\mu)\neq X$. See the conjecture below that relates to the case where we do not have this condition. The next proposition provides a partial converse to Proposition 1.

**Proposition 2 (negative answer to 2.):** *Assume that $X$ is separable. If there exists an open set $V \notin \{\emptyset, X\}$ such that the only homeomorphism $g$ with $g(V)=V$ is the identity, then there is a measure $\mu$ such that the only homeomorphism $h$ with such that $\mu$ and $h_*\mu$ are equivalent is the identity.*

We use the separability of $X$ (more precisely of $V^c$) to explicitely construct $\mu$. Maybe we can still construct $\mu$ under weaker conditions, or conversely find some non-separable $X$ for which Proposition 2 fails. A look at [examples of non-separable compact spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785087/non-separable-compact-space) (which are necessarily not metrizable) might help.

*proof:* The challenge consists in finding a suitable $\mu$. Since $X$ is separable, so is the compact space $V^c$: let $(v_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be sequence of $V^c$ that is dense in $V^c$, and $\mu = \sum_{n\geq 1} 2^{-n} \delta_{v_n}$. We can check that $\mu$ is a regular Borel measure with support $V^c$. Any homeomorphism $g$ such that $\mu$ and $g_*\mu$ are equivalent must have $V^c = g(V^c) \iff V = g(V)$, thus are the identity. $\square$

Examples of $X$ satisfying the assumption of Proposition 2 include spaces with an isolated point. Here is a somewhat complicated example without isolated point. We fix a numbering $(q_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of $\mathbb Q \cap (0,1)$, and construct a space $T$ as the limit of the following inductive construction --- which should remind you of Koch’s snowflake:

- start with $T = [0,1]$, and "distinguish" the sequence $(q_n)$.
- For every $n\geq 1$, glue $2n$ copies of $[0,2^{-n}]$ (with distinguished vertices $(2^{-n} q_k)_{k\geq 1}$) to the point $q_n$, by identifying the zeroes of the copies with $q_n$. This way, the $q_n$ all have non-homeomorphic neighborhoods ($q_n$’s neighborhood looks like a $2n+2$-pointed star), so any homeomorphism of $T$ must send $q_n$ to $q_n$ for every $n$. This ensures that the homeomorphisms of $T$ are the identity on the original copy of $[0,1]$.
- Iterate this process on the glued copies, making sure that the added copies are small enough so that everything converges **and that no distinguished vertex ever has the same number of branches than some other distinguished vertex.**

You should obtain $T$ that is a compact tree with infinitely many branches, with a countable number of branching points (the distinguished vertices) that are dense in $T$, such that the only homeomorphism of $T$ is the identity.

Now build $X$ by taking two copies $T_1$ and $T_2$ of $T$ and identifying the zero of $T_1$ with the one of $T_2$ and the one of $T_1$ with the zero of $T_2$. There are two homeomorphisms of $X$: the identity, and the exchange sending $T_1$ onto $T_2$. But once we fix any measure with support included in $T_1$, the only homeomorphism $g$ that ensures that $\mu$ and $g_*\mu$ are equivalent is the identity.

### Conjectured negative example with full support

Finally, here is a conjecture that, if true, provides a "natural" X and a rather natural $\mu$ with support $X$ for which 2. fails.

**Conjecture:** *Let $X=[0,1]$ equipped with the usual topology. The only homeomorphism that leaves $K = (\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]) \cup \{e^q, q\in \mathbb Q \cap (-\infty, 0]\}$ is the identity.*

Note that $X$ has a non-trivial homeomorphism group. $K$ is countable; let $(k_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be an enumeration of $K$, and define $\mu = \sum_{n\geq 1} 2^{-n} \delta_{k_n}$ --- we can check that it is Borel and regular. For every homeomorphism $g$ of $X$, $\mu$ and $g_*\mu$ are equivalent if and only if $g(K) = K$.
Then assuming this conjecture, the only homeomorphism with $\mu$ and $g_*\mu$ equivalent is the identity, providing a negative answer to 2. even for a "nice" $X$.

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant examples!